# Setting up Vim for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I work with Ruby on Rails and wish to use vim as the editor of choice. However, I can't find anywhere simple set of step by step,idiot proof, instructions with well explained steps as to how to set it up properly.

I wish to set vim properly, with nice plugins link vim for rails, nerdtree and stuff like that. Please help me, I would be most grateful.

So far I have installed RoR, vim, and git.

Comment: You need rails.vim https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails  Somewhere I remember a free screencast (not the paid one) about how to use it. I'll link it if I find it.

Comment: You can checkout my [dotfiles](https://github.com/hauleth/dotfiles) to see my `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably not going to find "idiot proof" anything when it comes to vim. However, the good news is that it's really not that hard once you do it a few times. If you can get [`NERD tree`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) installed, that's a good pattern for every other vim plugin out there.

The instructions for that plugin are simple enough.

> Unzip the archive into your ~/.vim directory. 
>   That should put NERD_tree.vim in ~/.vim/plugin and NERD_tree.txt in ~/.vim/doc.

You don't really *need* any plugins to work with Ruby in vim, but the short list of plugins that I use regularly are:

- [bufexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42) -- Easily the one that I use most often. Hundreds of times daily.
- [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [NERD tree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)
- [rails](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567)

Of those, the one that I use the most has nothing to do with Ruby specifically, but I find it to be faster than checking `:ls` for a buffer number. As long as I have `bufexplorer` plugged in, and [`ack`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ack-grep.1p.html) installed on the system, I'm ready to slay some Ruby code. The other plugins are just "nice-to-haves".

Answer (score 7):

I was fiddling around with vim plugins as well, then I found out, that [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) fits my needs quite well. It has a bunch of plugins I use regularily, like Ack.vim, NERDtree and SuperTab. And it is easy to install:

```
curl -Lo- http://bit.ly/janus-bootstrap | bash
```

I am not sure, if rails.vim is included or if I installed it myself. Check it out. Maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: I started with Janus myself - but I didn't like it as it's got SO much in it. I read somewhere you should know everything that you've set up your Vim to use, I'd avoid Janus and build up your vim environment from there. Mine now consists of vim-ruby, vim-rails and command-T via Pathogen of course.

Comment: Installing Janus is a great and super quick way to poke around with a very well put together vim config. Do that, then make your own :)

Answer (score 2):

There's also vim-ruby, vim-rake & vim-rvm to help you along too.

You could also consider using the duo of Pathogen & Vundle for auto installation. Pathogen was written by Tim Pope who wrote vim-rails. His Fugitive Git wrapper is invaluable also when using Git for source control for your Rails projects.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) (recommended)**

Copy and paste:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
    https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

If you're using Windows, change all occurrences of `~/.vim` to `~\vimfiles`.

Add this to your vimrc:

`execute pathogen#infect()`

If you're lacking a vimrc, `vim ~/.vimrc` and paste:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Now any plugins you wish to install can be extracted to a subdirectory under `~/.vim/bundle`, and they will be added to the 'runtimepath'. Observe:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-rails.git
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler.git
```

**AND/OR**

**Install [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) (includes some of the most popular vim plugins)**

`curl -Lo- https://bit.ly/janus-bootstrap | bash`

Resources:

- https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen
- https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails
- https://github.com/carlhuda/janus

Answer (score 0):

Check out this bundle I created for Vim - [smolnar/vim-rails-bundle](https://github.com/smolnar/vim-rails-bundle). Might help setting up your environment.